# How can shortkeys be captured by a Python program?

Tags: python, key, x11

I want to have a little Python program running in the background that monitors for certain shortkey presses (e.g. `Ctrl` `Alt` `direction key`). The idea is that these shortkeys can trigger various actions.

Here is the beginnings of an attempt, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing:

```
import Xlib
import Xlib.display

def process_event(event):

    keycode = event.detail
    if event.type == Xlib.X.KeyPress:
        print(keycode)

def main():

    # current display
    display    = Xlib.display.Display()
    rootWindow = display.screen().root

    # catch keypress events
    rootWindow.change_attributes(event_mask = Xlib.X.KeyPressMask)

    keys = [10, 11]

    for keycode in keys:
        rootWindow.grab_key(
            keycode,
            Xlib.X.Mod1Mask, #Xlib.X.AnyModifier,
            1,
            Xlib.X.GrabModeAsync,
            Xlib.X.GrabModeAsync
        )

    while True:
        event = rootWindow.display.next_event()
        process_event(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Grab first `press` if not `release` jump other condition.

Comment: @dsgdfg Hey there. Thanks for your suggestion. Could you give some more details? I'm not sure what you mean.